# Find a 99% confidence interval for the population mean for a sample of size 36 that yields a mean of 78 and a standard deviation of 6....

Tags: statistics

Find a 99% confidence interval for the population mean for a sample of size 36 that yields a mean of 78 and a standard deviation of 6. Assume sigma, the population standard deviation, is unknown.

A) (74.2, 81.8)
B) (76.00, 80.03)
C) (75.28, 80.72)
D) None of the above

Comment: What have you tried?  You are intended (though it is not stated) to assume a normal distribution.  You should have a formula for the variance of the mean of a sample.

Comment: No.${}{}{}{}{}$